# sphinkapi + stored procedures

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, sphinx

I'm trying to filter the query results by using a MySql Stored Procedure called "TESTACL" that returns a single integer value with the following code:

```
$cl->setSelect("*,IF(TESTACL(acl,3885,'#3885#-9#-80#-70#-14#',idset,idscatto) >= 2,1,0) AS permission");
```

I always get a syntax error:

```
ERROR: index test1: parse error: Sphinx expr: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ')' or ',' near '(acl,3885,'#3885#-9#-80#-70#-14#',idset,idscatto) >= 2,1,0)'
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use MySQL stored procedures in queries to Sphinx since Sphinx doesn't know anything about MySQL stored procedures.
You can do this within MySQL(!) queries when you index your data, but not when you do a search query.

What does a similar job on the search stage is UDFs (user defined functions). Sphinx supports it, but it's a little bit more difficult to implement than a mysql stored procedure.